# Suitable small/fast EEPROM for Atmega328

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

Looking for recommendation on EEPROM chip, which I can connect to Atmega328. The requirements are:

- at least 5-10Kbyte
- fast reading with Atmega. I expect reading one word about 1-5us, please advise if it's possible.
- I am going to store set of custom data structures and read them in the loop every 200ms.

Comment: I'd suggest using an SRAM IC with a SPI or I2C interface to cache the data in volatile memory, rather than doing thousands of repeated reads from the EEPROM. That'll increase your read speed and increase the lifetime of the EEPROM chip. Either way, Amtel make plenty of EEPROM devices suitable for general use.

Comment: @Poly: No, EEPROM is not worn out by reads, only writes.  The speed of reading a CPI or IIC SRAM would be limited by the bus, just like with EEPROM, so no advantage there.  If he setting these data stuctures once and then mostly reading them after that, EEPROM could be perfectly appropriate, especially if this data needs to be non-volatile.

Comment: Yes, I am setting it once in a while(during each device update) and mostly reading data. However, if it's possible to connect SRAM IC so that I can get approximately same reading speed as internal SRAM, I could put my data into PROGMEM and then during device startup copy data to external SRAM IC.

Comment: One other thing, does it need to be a mega328? There are other ATMega chips that have up to 16K of SRAM on chip, so if you do go with the caching based approach(which sounds smarter to me in general) you will not need to rely on external SRAM to implement it.

Comment: @David Perek: The reason of my post is to determine whether price-wise I can benefit from hooking up external memory. The price margin is very tight.

Comment: Could you just use the flash memory on the ATmega to store the data?

Comment: @geometrikal: I could, but then reading big amount of data in the loop from flash is very expensive operation in terms of timings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're just looking for nonvolatile storage, not necessarily an EEPROM.  Consider FRAM, like the [FM25V01](http://www.ramtron.com/files/datasheets/FM25V01_ds.pdf).  That particular chip stores 16Kb (larger sizes are available), has an expected endurance of *one hundred trillion* reads and writes, and has an SPI interface that can run at 40 MHz.  Your limiting factor here would probably be the ATMega328 speed.

Comment: The fastest way is of communicating with external memory is SPI?

Comment: On an Atmega328, you don't have much choice.  There's no external memory bus.